# Datagridview in C3

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am doing a selling invoice and i want the system to check if the quantity entered is a double value or no and if double value the quantity entered must be smaller than the quantity in the database.
The validation of checking if the user enter a double or no is working fine but the other part of the code is not working fine.the code works after the user leaved the cell and enter it again and if he edit it the system is keep saving the old value(wrong value) but for the first part it is working fine if he enters letters the system give him an error and when he correct it the system take the new value and let him leave the sell normally the problem is in the second part here is my code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 3 || e.ColumnIndex == 4 || e.ColumnIndex == 5 || e.ColumnIndex == 6 || e.ColumnIndex == 7) // 1 should be your column index
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(e.FormattedValue) != "")
            {
                double i;

                if (!double.TryParse(Convert.ToString(e.FormattedValue), out i))
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("Insert correct numbers");
                }
                else
                {

                    if (e.ColumnIndex == 5)
                    {
                        qty3 = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value);
                        string code = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                        sqlClass c = new sqlClass();
                        con = c.getcon();
                        con.Open();
                        c.command("select quantity from items where code='" + code + "'");
                        cmd = c.getcmd();
                        double qty2 = Convert.ToDouble(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
                        if (qty3 > qty2)
                        {
                            e.Cancel = true;
                            MessageBox.Show("You don't have enough quantity \n Quantity available is:" + qty2);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ErrorText = null;
                        }

                        con.Close();
                    }
                }

                }
            }         
    }
```

Comment: Please add a few line breaks! Then maybe one can find the actual question. C3?

Comment: C3 i mean C# sorry for the mistake